# What is the difference between static and dynamic trait mixins

Tags: scala, traits

Considering:

```
abstract class Base {
  def something() = println("Base")
}

trait TraitA extends Base {
    abstract override def something() = { super.something(); println("TraitA"); }
}

class Child extends Base {
    override def something() {
        println("Child")
    }
}
```

And then:

```
val x = new Child with TraitA
x.something()
```

I get:

```
Child
TraitA
```

But if I use:

```
class Child extends Base with TraitA {
    override def something() {
        println("Child")
    }
}

val x = new Child
x.something()
```

I'd get only:

```
Child
```

So what are the differentes of using a trait at construction site or declaration site? Can I have the first behavior (stackable traits) while extending/with'ing the trait in the declaration of the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Stackable traits in Scala refers to being able to mix in multiple
>   traits that work together to apply multiple modifications to a method.
>   This involves invoking super.theMethod and modifying its input and/or
>   output. But what is super in the context of a trait? The class (or
>   trait) the trait extends from? The class the trait is being mixed
>   into? It depends! All the mixed in traits and all the superclasses are
>   linearized. super invokes the nearest preceding definition further up
>   the chain.

[read full post](http://www.lorrin.org/blog/2012/08/09/scalas-abstract-override-stackable-traits-and-object-hierarchy-linearization/)

In your case:
1. super.something() == Child.something()
2. super.something() == Base.something() and Child.something() overrides whole chain

Type of mixin doesn't matter:

```
class Child2 extends Child with TraitA

val x2 = new Child2
x2.something() 
/* 
   Child
   TraitA
*/

class Child3 extends Base with TraitA
val x3 = new Child3
x3.something()
/* 
   Base
   TraitA
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you override the method of `Base` first and then you mix `TraitA` which will stack.

In the second example, first you mix `TraitA` and then you override the resulting (stacked) method.